# GSON: Convert JSON To Object with ignorance

Tags: java, gson, android

I had JSON model for success some this

```
{
    data: {
        .....
    }
}
```

so I've create model:

```
Class Model{
    public Data data;
}
```

and I've used 
`new Gson().fromJson(Model.class)` to convert in Object. It works fine. Now my problem starts with when I get error in same API and its json Get changed

```
{
    message: {
        .....
    }
}
```

I want to use same model to be serialized in Json.

```
Class Model{
    public Data data;
    public Massage message;
}
```

But it gives me following Exception: `Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 13`

Comment: There is not enough information here. I suspect there could be a problem within your `Massage` class and the related data. Something is not right as the field is called `m` but in the json it is called `message`, but that will not cause the "expected string" on its own.

Comment: as @weston pointed out, your model variable name must be equal do the json object name, in this case, your "Massage m" sould be "Massage message". I believe the problem is inside your Massage Object in which, somewhere, you have a field as String but the type of the argument is an Object.

Comment: variable m is just for example .let me change in question.

Comment: Please put the completely code how you parsing Json String.
Because I have everything working when I do the next: 
Model gMessage = new Gson().fromJson(jsonMessage, Model.class);

Answer (score 0):

Just configure and use `ObjectMapper` from Jackson lib:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.3</version>
</dependency>
```

The mapper should be defined as

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

Please see full Demo example

```
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String jsonData = "{" +
                "    \"data\": {" +
                "    }" +
                "}";
        String jsonMessage = "{" +
                "    \"message\": {" +
                "    }" +
                "}";

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

        Model modelData = mapper.readValue(jsonData, Model.class);
        Model modelMessage = mapper.readValue(jsonMessage, Model.class);


        System.out.println(modelData);
        System.out.println(modelMessage);


    }
}


class Model {

    private Data data;
    private Message message;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Model{" +
                "data=" + data +
                ", message=" + message +
                '}';
    }

    public Data getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Data data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Message getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(Message message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    private static class Data {}
    private static class Message {}
}
```

BTW, ObjectMapper is Thread Safe, so you can define one constant to not create it each time when you read Json.

More info you can find here: [http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html)

Comment: Question is about gson, not jackson.

Comment: @weston If you want to get an answer related only to Gson lib you must define in in the header and write about it in the question that you do want to fix it only using Gson lib. For now there is no such info, so please add it to not waste other people's time.

Comment: Well it is in the question quite clearly and as for the title, no, that is what tags are for. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Comment: If you don't describe what do you exactly want, other people will think out for you and you will never get the appropriate answer. In this case I saw that you are not familiar with Jackson Lib, that much more powerful that Gson.